# What does the color coding mean on the network graph in the Timeline panel?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

The portion of the timeline panel which I'm referring to is highlighted red in the image below.

[image: network graph in timeline panel]

I assume that each bar represents a resource. What does the lighter and darker colored portions of each resource represent? And what do the blue, yellow, and green resources represent?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Colors are represented as such:

- **Blue** is HTML
- **Gold** is Script
- **Purple** is Style
- **Green** is Media
- **Grey** is Other/Misc request types

These are currently found on line 428 of [`devtools/front_end/timeline/TimelineUIUtils.js`](https://cs.chromium.org/chromium/src/third_party/blink/renderer/devtools/front_end/timeline/TimelineUIUtils.js?dr&q=TimeLineUI&g=0&l=428).

```
switch (category) {
  case categories.HTML: return "hsl(214, 67%, 66%)";
  case categories.Script: return "hsl(43, 83%, 64%)";
  case categories.Style: return "hsl(256, 67%, 70%)";
  case categories.Media: return "hsl(109, 33%, 55%)";
  default: return "hsl(0, 0%, 70%)";
}
```

The lighter areas of the bars are the time spent **waiting** for a request. The dark ticks are the time spent conducting the **transfer** of content. This is discovered looking at the [`drawRequest`](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/timeline/TimelineEventOverview.js&q=drawRequest&sq=package:chromium&type=cs&l=211) method of the `TimelineEventOverview` file.

Comment: The source code link TimelineUIUtils.js is no longer valid, but a description of the color coding of the "Performance" tab (formerly "Timeline" tab), can be found at [https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/evaluate-performance/reference). e.g. search for "green" on that page until you find the definition of green for a given section of the tab/graph (in this case, the Network section).

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This is from the Chromium Source Project:
https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:out/Debug/gen/devtools/network/NetworkWaterfallColumn.js;l=115-128?q=waterfall%20color&ss=chromium%2Fchromium%2Fsrc&originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F

and

https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:third_party/devtools-frontend/src/front_end/timeline/TimelineUIUtils.js;l=467-480?q=TimelineUIUtils.js&ss=chromium&originalUrl=https:%2F%2Fcs.chromium.org%2F